Compare expected and observed feature combinations in biological samples
Background research:
The hypothesis studied here is whether or not effects such as co-selection or cross-resistance have an impact on the number observed multiple drug resistances in biological samples.
I have categorical data for 1000 biological samples and 4 features (A,B,C,D) telling me whether or not the sample is resistant (R) or susceptible (S) to the drug A,B,C,D.
On this basis I can calculate observed frequencies for each drug resistance across all samples:
P(A = "R") = 0.4
P(B = "R") = 0.3
P(C = "R") = 0.3
P(D = "R") = 0.2

On the other hand I observe multiple drug resistancies, and I want to find out whether the combination of resistance is significantly more frequent than expected :
P(observed) = P(A = R + B = R + C = R + D = R) = 0.1
P(expected) = P(A = R)* R(B = R) * P(C = R) * P(D = R) =
0.4*0.3*0.3*0.2

Given the large difference between P(observed) = 0.1 and P(expected)=0.0072
I want to use chisq.test funtion in R to compare those ratios. Is there a better test ? How to set up the contingency table ?

What is your research question, specifically?

The hypothesis is that there is some kind of resistance co-selection or cross-resistance, which should have an impact on the number of combinations.

"Is there a better test?" - I digress, but, in future, you should consider designing your experiment including the statistical test before conducting the experiment.  Besides the interpretation of p-values hinging crucially on the statistical test not being ad hoc, you will get the benefit of power analyses and the like.

Anyhoo, you might want to look into Fisher's Test.  I think that if you run a single test on the whole contingency table, you'll get answers like "these variables are not independent", but not info about which of A,B,C,D had the effect.  You might want to consider comparing them pairwise, but this again affects interpretation of p-values, see here

Pairwise combinations do not really reflect the situation, in which we observe patterns of co-occurence for 3 or 4 features. That is why am looking for ways to assess those combinations.

pair-wise and three-wise and four-wise as well?  That's 11 tests.  Take care with interpreting/reporting results - these tests aren't independent, so the usual "1-in-20 Type I error" doesn't apply.

Are all the four features defined for every sample? Do they co-occur? E.g., could you do a Fisher exact test of resistance occurring given that A=R+B=R vs. A=R+B=NR?
